# How to call getServletContext() equivalent in AppEngineMapper derived class?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I have a Mapper class which extends `AppEngineMapper<Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable>`.

Now inside my map function (`public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context)`), I need to get access to `PersistenceManager`. To get singleton `PersistenceManager`, I need `ServletContext` object.

Typically, in a `HTTPServlet` extended class, I call `getServletContext()` and pass it to get `PersistenceManager` object. But in Mapper extended class, I don't have or can call `getServletContext()`.

Can anyone advice on how to get servletcontext in my mapper class or if there is a way to pass servlet context from my servlet to Mapper extended class? I am using auto-mapreduce (programmatically) through a cron job.